# Filtering data by category

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a javascript function that filters categories. There is also interleaving of lists in php.blade.

The problem is that alternation only works when filtering has All, and when we select a specific category, alternation does not work. How can this be fixed?

### JavaScript

```
$('.category-filter_item').click(function(){
    $('.category-filter_item').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    var dataFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('.blog-list').hide()
    $(dataFilter).show()
})
```

### php.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="category-filter" id="filter">
    <div class="category-filter_item active" data-filter="*">All</div>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="category-filter_item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->title }}</div>
    @endforeach
</div>

@foreach ($blogs as $index => $blog)
    <div class="blog-list">
        @if ($index % 2 === 1)  //Alternation
            <div class="blog blog--left" >
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @else

            <div class="blog blog--right">
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

### Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $blogs = Blog::all();
        $categories = Category:all();

        return view('blog', compact('blogs', 'categories'));
    }
```

Comment: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"**You should not force a tag into your title.** Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for. Additionally, tags appear on the question page, so other people will take them into account when answering your question."_

Comment: As in, the list doesn't show "All" when you click on an already active tag?

Comment: When I click on **All**, all blogs are displayed and the alternation is working properly. When I select the **desired category**, all blogs from this category are displayed, but alternation does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Change the way of styling. currently, you are using the `blog--left` and `blog--right` for the left and right section remove that class from the div and apply the below style to the style.

```css
.blog {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I'm new to javascript, but I don't know much about jquery and ajax. And the second method also did not understand how you can automatically apply the style?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated the answer see if this can help you. i have attached sample style code.

Comment: I have separate styles for the blog-right `.blog--right { .blog_title { text-align: right; }}` , if i remove it, how can i apply it later?

Answer (score 0):

Alternation doesn't work, because you have your "alternation" implemented with PHP. PHP - is server side. You are implementing filtering on js - clients side. So when you select any filter you page (html) is not re-rendering (`@foreach ($blogs as $index => $blog)` is not running anymore because it is PHP). So my suggestion would be:

- remove classes blog--left, blog--right
- add style for the .blog class .blog{width:50%; float: left;} (if your .blog has any margins you can try width 49% or less)

Comment: It's just that I use different styles for the left blog and the right blog, and if one of them is deleted, then everything will not be as it should be. Is it possible to do the alternation function somehow in the javascript?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it will be over-complicated. Why don't yo want to solve it with the styles. Solution is pretty simple. Do you have your styles in css file?

Comment: Yes, I have separate styles for the blog-right `.blog--right { .blog_title { text-align: right; }}` , if i delete it, how can i apply it later?

Comment: then you can use .blog-list { .blog:nth-child(2n) { text-align: right; }} (check css :nth-child(2n))